# How do you write XML rules with XPATH?

Tags: xml, xpath, sonarqube

The [SonarQube documentation of XPATH rules](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules+using+XPath) only contains instructions on how to add to the server but how do you actually write one. I need examples.

Comment: This is not really the place for this kind of questions.. You should show an effort and show what you tried yourself, people won't solve your problems for you. For examples, I would suggest Googling..

Comment: Already tried but limited success there. If someone could provide an example, which i cannot find, it'd be very helpful